# My Product Manager Traveling To My City, Should I Meet Her In Person?

Tags: colleagues, travel

I've been working remotely for a year now for this company. On our daily meeting, my PM said she will travel to my country tomorrow.

Is it okay if I reach out to her and ask if I can treat her meal from my country? Is it appropriate?

Comment: Just ask them but do so politely and make clear you totally understand if the answer is no.

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATED my answer** after the OP commented below that the PM goes to his city to be on vacation:

You could send her an email wishing her a great vacation, and telling her that if she and her family/friends need anything, they can contact you as you are a local and familiar with the city. Then, it will be up to her to contact you if she wants to meet you.

Her main purpose to go to your city is to be on vacation (and **NOT** to meet you or any other team members). So, she will not be offended if you won't meet and greet her.

Perhaps, she may even want to be left alone with her family/friends, and want to stay away from anything that reminds her of work when she is on vacation. (That is why it is called a **vacation**).

Comment: it is only I who works remotely atm, and she is Japanese, while here in Indonesia is pretty normal to greet someone who comes to ur city. I'm kinda scared to like disturb the vacation, but also kinda scare not to greet her lol

Comment: It's nice to offer. She probably can't rearrange her plans on a day's notice (especially if she is traveling with others) to fit you in, but by offering, you get "credit" for wanting to do the polite thing even if you don't end up doing it.

Answer (score 6):

Strong suggestion: Ask your direct manager.

In general, it does no harm to say "if you'd like, we could get together for a get-to-know-each-other meeting, in the office or over a meal." Just don't read too much into the answer whether it is yes *or* no.

If it's a vacation, the answer will almost certainly be "some other time". Though I've altered my own travel plans at times to spend time talking to someone I already work closely with.

Who pays for a meal is very much a matter of local custom and company policy as well as who is issuing the invitation.